# How to check in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to check if all "Phrases" in "DropDown" contain all "Terms" instead of having to display them all

[image]

and I do not know what to provide for everyone, if you want me to provide something please comment below. Thanks !

Comment: You might want to show the code where you're creating that `select` dropdown.

Comment: yes, But ,"Term" is a word and "Phrase" is a sentence, my problem is how to press "Term" then "Phrase" drops down the sentences that contain "Term" in it. instead of every press it displays it all.

Comment: @vinduongtang could do it with Javascript.